# Manipulate string data into excel file

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

I have data in string format like:

```
str1 = "[0,-1.5],[-12.5,1.5],[12.5,1.5],[12.5,-1.5],[-12.5,-1.5])"
```

I want to put this data into an excel file. means 1st value from the array will go in x Col and 2nd value will go in Y col. this will be repeated until the whole string will be added to the x and y columns. I am attempting like, first convert the string into dataframe and then dataframe to an excel file. but it's giving me an error of **"Empty DataFrame"**.

```
    bad_chars = [';', ':', '(', ')', '[', ']']
s = ""
for i in str1:
    if i not in bad_chars:
        s += i
print(s)

StringData = StringIO(s)


df = pd.read_csv(StringData, sep=",")

# Print the dataframe
print(df)
```

[image]

Comment: Is `str1` correctly specified? Does it have only one round bracket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`pandas.Series.str.extractall`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) :

```
out = (
        pd.Series([str1])
            .str.extractall(r"(-?\d+\.?\d*,-?\d+\.?\d*)")
            .reset_index(drop=True)
            [0].str.split(",", expand=True)
            .rename(columns= {0: "X", 1: "Y"})
            .applymap('="{}"'.format)
      )
​
```

##### # Output :

```
print(out)

          X        Y
0      ="0"  ="-1.5"
1  ="-12.5"   ="1.5"
2   ="12.5"   ="1.5"
3   ="12.5"  ="-1.5"
4  ="-12.5"  ="-1.5"
```

Then, you can use [**`pandas.DataFrame.to_excel`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) to put this dataframe in a spreadsheet:
`out.to_excel("path_to_the_file.xlsx", index=False)`

Comment: it's extracting the data but there is one issue. I have very large data, like these values [0.55,-2.1375],[0.55,-1.9625]. it should extract 

X:             Y:
0.55,      -1.1375,
0.55,      -1.9625,

but I am getting wrong like this

X:             Y:
55,      -1.1375,
55,      -1.9625,

Comment: I updated the regex pattern ;)

Comment: it should be 0.55 in X col but I am getting 55 instead

Comment: Have you checked my updated answer ?

Comment: It's an Excel problem if this one get rid of the leading zero, I updated my answer to handle this ;)